# Send specific bytes over USB/MIDI

Tags: usb, midi

I need to send specific bytes over USB/MIDI. How can I accomplish 
this?

I want to program a midi controller with an Arduino. But first, I want to test how I have to send the messages.

Answer (score 8):

The [amidi](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/amidi.1.html) tool allows you to send arbitrary MIDI commands.
For example:

```
amidi -l                                # find out what the port number is
amidi -p hw:42,0 -S "C0 65 90 30 7F"
```